# location of .htaccess file

Tags: html, .htaccess, web, pagespeed

/var/www/html/My_project_folder   is the path to my project. I did not find .htaccess file. I want to paste my edited .htaccess file . but i am not sure in which location i need to put? 
My htaccess file code is--

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 <IfModule mod_expires.c>

 # Enable expirations
 ExpiresActive On

 # Default directive
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

 # My favicon
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year”

 # Images
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"

 # CSS
 ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month”

 # Javascript
 ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

 </IfModule>

 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

This code i added in .htaccess file to speed up of my site. Please help me for location of .htaccess file. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

Usually this file goes to the root of your website (where your `index.php` file is). If there is none, you can create a new file. But watch out not to create something like ".htaccess.txt" if you do it with notepad (which usually appends .txt to all files).

Answer (score 2):

You need to paste the .htaccess file on the root of your project.
It's possible that your .htaccess is hidden ... try to look into the folder using the terminal instead of the DM and if it's not there try to create a new file from the terminal using the command.

nano .htaccess (linux users)
edit .htaccess (windows users)

Comment: root of my project means under project folder i need to creat this .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes exactly in "/var/www/html/My_project_folder". and check if you have the mod enabled on apache using "a2enmod rewrite" otherwise your .htaccess file will be useless

Comment: Thank you. May i know how to enable mod by ssh?

Comment: if i paste .htaccess file under www will it make trouble to server. because firstly i was trying so and i am getting “Network connection closed unexpectedly”

Comment: I think you have the virtual host configured with the www directory as root directory...so the .htaccess is working but it can't find the correct path ... do a test with a simple .htaccess like this  http://www.qualitytuts.com/check-htaccess-is-working-or-not-on-server/  here you can find the host configuration example http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html