# Routes not working on Slim framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

I am learning the slim framework. I got a point where I have to set up my webserver such that I can see something like http://slimapp instead of http://localhost/slimapp/public/index.php.

I have included a .htaccess file in the public folder of my project like so

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I have also set up a virtual host on my wamp server

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp64\www\slimapp\public"
    ServerName slimapp

    <Directory "C:\wamp64\www\slimapp\public">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also added this to my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 slimapp
```

I restarted my server but I get a 'Not Found' error when I try to access my routes.

```
"Not Found
The requested URL /hello/uche was not found on this server."
```

This is my index.php file

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $name = $request->getAttribute('name');
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");

    return $response;
});
$app->run();
```

Please help me here.

Comment: Have you run `a2enmod rewrite`? Or for windows - https://webdevdoor.com/php/mod_rewrite-windows-apache-url-rewriting

Comment: Still not working

Comment: It is being called @Nima

Answer (score 0):

try to move .htaccess file to root directory

Comment: you must provide more detail to your answer.

Comment: @muhammad-omer-aslam this problem already discussed
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756768/location-of-htaccess-file

Comment: you should look [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still face this problem, this is how I solved it:

Enable model rewrite. In your terminal type:

sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo service apache2 restart

http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/problems/10216-beginner-routes-not-working